# Download the file to specific location?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have attached the link below, I use to run this link in google chrome, after that it will automatically start downloading CSV in the downloads folder with the default name `"xxx.csv"`. I tried multiple codes to download the file and copy it to a specific location with a specific name but not achieved.

```
def download_files():
    
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"}

    for idFile in report_files:
        login = session.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('USER','PASSWORD'), verify=False)
```

Sample link: `https://xxx.corp.xxcloud.net/exportdata/getdata?Format=CSV&QueryID=xxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the resoonse of your get request, you need to write it to disk.

```
import requests

url = 'http://google.com/index.html'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
with open('target_path.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
}

for idFile in report_files:
    login = session.get(
        f"https://xxx.corp.xxcloud.net/exportdata/getdata?Format=CSV&QueryID={idFile}",
        auth=HttpNtlmAuth('USER','PASSWORD'),
        verify=False
    )
    with open(f"{idFile}.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(login.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: it shows an error for the above code "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"
i changed it  f.write(str(login.content)) and it got executed by I can see only data in 1row

Comment: Ok I have fixed it, you need to add `.decode('utf-8')` when writing the file

Comment: `code`with open(f"{idFile}.csv", "w",encoding='utf-8') as f:
 `code`           f.write(login.content.decode('utf-8'))

I have done a small adjustment to your code now it working well, the only thing is giving empty rows in between each row? can you help me here?